# java spring bean registration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

We got absolutely simple application with 2 pages.

Code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page2</title>
</head>
<body>
page2
<a href="page1url">page1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller Code:

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value ="/page1url")
    public String page1( ) {
        return "page1";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/page2url")
    public String page2( ) {
        return "page2";
    }
}
```

To make it work we need register Controller.
Way 1. Classic work fine. Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

    <bean class="controller.MainController"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Way 2. Using Spring-context
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="*"/>

    <!--<bean class="controller.MainController"/>-->

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Way 2 Doesn't work.

web.xml is simple and basic code

**Question:**
*Why Spring-context variant doesn't work and how to fix it?*

P.S. Apologize for a lot of code

Comment: Which error do you have?

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception 
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add these line in your `Spring-context` file like this:

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />        
 <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
```

Removing `base-package="*"`

Comment: Don't know. I pressed +

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to Spring-context:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Full code here [link](https://github.com/WalterP/Spring2pagesSimple/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml)

Comment: @WladZ Oh, It seems the single wildcard(`*`) doesn't work. How about this: `<context:component-scan base-package="**"/>`. I'm not sure tho...

Comment: I Add
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
and chenged 
 <context:component-scan base-package="*"/> to
 <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>

and it worked.
Thanks all